# Using function to convert array elements to references suddenly returns values instead

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli, php-7

After upgrading to PHP 7.0.9 my site broke down (previous version was also in 7.0.x). Apparently something changed regarding references in the latest update. I am using the mysqli functiuon **mysqli_stmt_bind_param** via **call_user_func_array** which needs values as refrences. I am therefor using a function for converting the array from values to refrences, like this:

```
function refValues($array){

    $refArray = array();
    foreach($array as $key => $value){
        $refArray[$key] =& $array[$key];
    }

    return $refArray;
}
```

Something is going wrong when the array is returned as all the references are changed back to values. This was not the case earlier as it worked perfectly before updating php. A temporary fix is to not use a function, but i don't really want to do that. Anyone have any suggestions? Is this a bug introduced in the latest release of php, or a breaking change i don't know about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your function as

```
function refValues(&$array){
```

so that you're passing $array "by reference" otherwise your $refArray references pointing to an array value that's only scoped inside the function

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/7pZ2e)

Comment: Thanks, that solved it. Can't believe i missed that. Sort of makes me even more curious to why it worked before updating to the latest php 7 release